# CollaborationGroup records not accessible in post installation script

Tags: postinstall

I am trying to read CollaborationGroup records in post installation script.
My class implements InstallHandler and is without sharing, Still no records are returned by following query even though record does exist in same org.

List myList = [select id from CollaborationGroup];

No exception is being thorwn, only records are not visible. Any Help